# Echo or Print after = in PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

```
while ($apa = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $username = print($apa['username']);
    $pass = print(md5(md5($apa['password'])));

     require '../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        require '../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'mail.royaleducation.web.id';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = 'xxxxxx';                 // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = 'xxxxxx';                           // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom($email,$name);
        $mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo($email);
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                    // Set email format to HTML>
        $mail->msgHTML(

            "<center><h1>Your data</h1></center><br><br>
            username =".$username."<br>
            password =".$password



        );
```

the **$username** and **$password** won't appear..
am i wrong to put print after **$username** and **$password**??
or there is another way to print out the value in phpmailer?? because if i type  or **echo** inside **$mail->msgHTML** , its getting error

Comment: You're not really sending usernames and passwords over plaintext in an email, are you? Granted, the password is *double*-`md5`'d, but `md5` is also broken. Why are you doing this, exactly?

Comment: the md5 is not broken, i doubled it.. i wanna test it exactly, but if i forgot the password, i must get the username and password from database and send it again to my email.. the problem is, i got the value of my username and password, but it won't appear in my email..

Comment: `md5` is *very* broken in terms of security. You should *never* use it for new projects, and should move old projects away from it. Even if you're doing it twice, it's *still* a broken algorithm.

Comment: You should also never send your users' credentials over email. If they need access to their account, they should be able to [*reset* their password securely](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/09/untangling-forget-me-knot-secure-account-recovery-made-simple) instead of just having it sent to them.

Comment: okkay, i will change it later.. but how to echo the value..??

Comment: i'm not using laravel now.. lil bit confuse haha..

Comment: "I will change it later" – and thus are security holes born. You're not just using md5, but you're storing plain text passwords. This is about as broken as it's possible to be.

Comment: If you're using the autoloader or composer (which you should be), you don't need to load the PHPMailer class manually as well.

Comment: i change the method now, with some random code and reset the password securely.. thanks all btw

Comment: _"the md5 is not broken, i doubled it"_ LOL damn it I just spit coffee on my monitor...

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`print`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php) function, parameters show on output and `print` always return 1, so you can't use for assign values.

If you have problem `$mail->msgHTML` function you can use `$mail->Body` as below:

```
while ($apa = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $username = $apa['username'];
    $pass = md5(md5($apa['password']));

     require '../phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        require '../phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
            $mail->Host = 'mail.royaleducation.web.id';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Username = 'idxxxx';                 // SMTP username
            $mail->Password = 'xxxxx';                           // SMTP password
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
            $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom($email,$name);
        $mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
        $mail->addReplyTo($email);
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                    // Set email format to HTML>
        $mail->Body ="<center><h1>Your data</h1></center><br><br>username =".$username."<br>password =".$password;
```

Comment: so i can't use the print or echo after = ??

Comment: If use print, your variable always is 1 .

Comment: yaaa i got that 1 in result. so how i can echo the variable inside $mail->msgHTML ???

Comment: Instead of `$mail->msgHTML()` use `$mail->Body=`.

Comment: $mail->msgHTML(
                $mail->Body = "<html> <?php echo $username ?></html>"
            ); if type like this its getting error..

Comment: it still empty in my email.. just like this username =
password =

Comment: Are you sure `$username` and `$password` have value? What is output of `var_dump($username)` or `var_dump($password)`?

Comment: i'm sure, because i selected it from database.. it must be username = stevan and password = 12345678

Comment: What is output of var_dump($username) or var_dump($password)?

Comment: stevanbf29bb235b214c636876ac24370719c9array(6) { [0]=> string(6) "stevan" ["username"]=> string(6) "stevan" [1]=> string(32) "244d72933cd9aa2acc543f28900b1d53" ["password"]=> string(32) "244d72933cd9aa2acc543f28900b1d53" [2]=> string(21) "stevanlai04@gmail.com" ["email"]=> string(21) "stevanlai04@gmail.com" } those are the var_dump my username and encrypted password